# How to have more than 2 data in a map c++

Tags: c++

Currently I have roughly 2 data in a tuple, one is string and the other is a tuple
I want to write the data to the file which currently look something like this

```
Name  Indian Math English History Moral AverageScore
Anu     100   100   100     100    100      100
```

But What I want i want is

```
StudentNo Gender Name  Indian Math English History Moral AverageScore
  0223      M     Anu     100   100   100     100    100      100
```

Trying to add StudentNo and Gender, but the problem is Map only can have 2 data, if I put more than 1 data, the IDE will spit an error. Check the code in the while loop.

Here's the code

```
//  Function to modify a student's exam scores.
void Student::modifyScore(string newName, int newIndian, int newEnglish, int newMath, int newHistory, int newMoral) {

    // How to add more than 1 data?
    map<string, tuple<int, int, int, int, int> > data;

    // Read file and fill data map
    ifstream studentRec("StudentRecord.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(studentRec, line))
    {
        string name;

       int studentNo;
        // char gender; Trying to add these two.
       // string name;
       int indian, english, math, history, moral;

       stringstream ss(line);
       ss >> name >> indian >> english >> math >> history >> moral;
       data[name] = make_tuple(indian, english, math, history, moral);

    }

    studentRec.close();

    // Modify data
    data[newName] = make_tuple(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral);
    // Open same file for output, overwrite existing data
    ofstream ofs("StudentRecord.txt");

    for (auto entry = data.begin(); entry != data.end(); ++entry)
    {
        tie(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral) = entry->second;
        int average = averageScore(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral);

        ofs << left <<  setw(15) << entry->first << setw(15) << newIndian << setprecision(2) << newEnglish << setw(15) << right << newMath << setw(15) << newHistory << setw(15) <<  newMoral << average << endl;
    }
    ofs.close();


}
```

What this program does is modify the existing data in the file with the new data. 
 I just couldn't figure out on how to modify this function to suits my need.

Comment: Don't understand your problem. What do u mean "can have 2 data" ? `map` is an array with {`key`, `value`} pairs. `key` can be more complex data type then `std::string`. Do you want to make `StudentNo`, `Name` and `Gender` as your `key` in the map ?

Comment: Yes exactly but I couldn't make studentNo and gender to be the key because I can't have more than 2 data type. For example,  I cant have map <int, string char, tuple<int,int,int,int,int> > data

Comment: why do you want gender to be a key? Please read about mappings and understand what *key* and *value* in this contex means. You simply want a compound value, e.g.: an object.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Because I need to overwrite the file with Gender and StudentNo data.

Comment: The key is used for lookup. If you don't look up *by gender*, it's not a key.

Comment: @airsoftFreak, Karoly Horvath want to say that you don't need  map here. You just need to create an object that will hold all needed information (`StudentNo`, `Name` etc). Read your file into an array (vector) of such objects. Then modify this objects as you want and put them back to the file

Comment: @user2451677 can you show me the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: @airsoftFreak, ok, wait for a minute, I will write it

Comment: Or just add new fields to the tuple.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array

Comment: @KarolyHorvath can you show the answer so I could accept it?

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it work? If not, update the question with the attempt and the error message.

Comment: If i add new Field to the tuple, I need to overwrite it again with new data?

Comment: Sry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath So basically If add new field to the tuple what would happen?

Comment: There's going to be a shining light and rushing noise. Then something will click in your mind and you'll get enlightened. Alternatively, you'll get some compiler error messages.

Comment: Is moral a subject at school?

Comment: @Karo ly a shining light followed by a rushing noise is a bad curry the night before

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your map(especially key of map), add additional fields in  tuple.   Please let me know does it work.

```
//  Function to modify a student's exam scores.
    void Student::modifyScore(string newName, int newIndian, int newEnglish, int newMath, int newHistory, int newMoral) {


    map<int, tuple<char,std::string,int, int, int, int, int> > data;

    // Read file and fill data map
    ifstream studentRec("StudentRecord.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(studentRec, line))
    {
       string name;
       int studentNo;
       char gender; Trying to add these two.

       int indian, english, math, history, moral;

       stringstream ss(line);
       ss >> studentNo>>gender>>name >> indian>> english >> math >> history >> moral;
       data[studentNo] = make_tuple(gender,name,indian, english, math, history, moral);

    }

    studentRec.close();

    // Modify data
    data[studentNo] = make_tuple(newGender,newName,newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral);
    // Open same file for output, overwrite existing data
    ofstream ofs("StudentRecord.txt");

    for (auto entry = data.begin(); entry != data.end(); ++entry)
    {
        tie(newGender,newName,newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral) = entry->second;
        int average = averageScore(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral);

        ofs << left <<  setw(15) << entry->first << setw(15) <<newGender<<newName<< newIndian << setprecision(2) << newEnglish << setw(15) << right << newMath << setw(15) << newHistory << setw(15) <<  newMoral << average << endl;
    }
    ofs.close();


}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you want to make `StudentNo`, `Gender` and `Name` fields as `unique` key of your `map` (btw, why not only `StudentNo` ?). So you need to put them into one data type, like this:

```
struct StudentKey
{
    int id;
    char gender;
    std::string name;
};
```

and provide `operator<`, because you are using `std::map` with default comparator. But don't do this!
If you just want to read data from file, modify it and put back into file, then you simply need something like this:

```
struct Student
{
    int StudentNo;
    char Gender;
    std::string Name;
    int Indian;
    int Math;
    int English;
    int History;
    int Moral;
    int AverageScore;
};

    //  Function to modify a student's exam scores.
void Student::modifyScore(const Student& newStudent) {
    std::vector<Student> data;
    // Read file and fill data map
    ifstream studentRec("StudentRecord.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(studentRec, line))
    {
        Student s{};
        stringstream ss(line);
        if(ss >> s.StudentNo >> s.Gender >> s.Name >> s.Indian >> s.Math >> s.English >> s.History >> s,Moral)
            data.push_back(s);
    }

    studentRec.close();

    // Modify data
    data.push_back(newStudent);
    // Open same file for output, overwrite existing data
    ofstream ofs("StudentRecord.txt");

    for(auto& s : data)
    {
        s.AverageScore = averageScore(s.Indian, ...);

        ofs << left <<  setw(15) << s.StudentNo << ... << average << endl;
    }
    ofs.close();
```

}

Comment: Contrary to what he said, he clearly doesn't want a compound key.

Comment: Hm. That's why I said "don't do this". I just wrote `StudentKey` as an example of compound key. But anyway this is not important, Thanks